# Insert Moments on Googleplus with PHP: almost done... just an non-object error to solve

Tags: insert, google-plus

I am trying to post a moments on my Googleplus Business Page though a PHP script.

To call the Google APIs I am using service accounts.

The following code give this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in (last Line)".... could you help me to solve this prob?

```js
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

// Set your client id, service account name, and the path to your private key.
// For more information about obtaining these keys, visit:
// https://developers.google.com/console/help/#service_accountsconst CLIENT_ID = 'MYID';
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'MYACCOUNT';

// Make sure you keep your key.p12 file in a secure location, and isn't
// readable by others.
const KEY_FILE = 'MYAUTHFILE';

// Load the key in PKCS 12 format (you need to download this from the
// Google API Console when the service account was created.
$client = new Google_Client();

$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);
$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction'),$key));


// Create moment that does not have a URL.
$item_scope = new Google_ItemScope();
$item_scope->setId("MYGOOGLEPAGEID");
$item_scope->setType("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity");
$item_scope->setName("The Google+ Platform");
$item_scope->setDescription("A page that describes just how awesome Google+ is!");
$item_scope->setImage("https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing.png");

$moment_body = new Google_Moment();
$moment_body->setType("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity");
$moment_body->setTarget($item_scope);
$momentResult = $plus->moments->insert('me', 'vault', $moment_body);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you didn't initialize the Plus API Client:

```
$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);
```

You will also have to use the correct scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` instead of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction`

And I'm not sure if writing moments will work with service accounts...

Comment: Thank you vey much. You helped me a lot. Now another problem... i dont have enough rights: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/moments/vault: (403) Insufficient Permission' in google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php:66

Answer (score 2):

You can only write moments on behalf of an authenticated user when you use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` scope. You can't use a service account to do this. More so you cannot authenticate as a Google+ Page so writing moments isn't possible in your scenario.

Do you think you might be able to edit your post to explain why you want to write moments on behalf of a Page? What is the goal that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Brett, Thank you very much for your concern. The goal is to escape the user authentication and consent of Google... https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?hl=de#scenarios

Comment: Hi Brett, I thought that for writting moments only client object has to be created ( https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert )... How should I do to publish a moment with a PHP code and escape the user authentication and consent of Google ?

Comment: ...by saying escaping the user authentification and consent... I mean using the SERVICE ACCOUNTS authentification instead.

Comment: Its not possible to do this with a service account, they aren't users and don't have profiles. Moments are tied to an individual user's profile.

You explain what you're trying to do but not why or the motivation behind this.